# Late-bound version of RegisterInstance in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, ninject, late-binding

In our project, we use Unity as a dependency injection framework. Now I am faced with a situation, where I need a late-bound version of `IUnityContainer.RegisterInstance()`.

In ninject, the code I am trying to do, would look something like this:

```
this.Bind<IMyInterface>().ToMethod(context => GetMyObjectLateBound());
```

In Unity, however, I have not found a way of doing this, so far.

The reason, why I need this, is that the Instance of `IMyInterface` is not created yet by the time, that the binding happens and the object creation is also not handled by Unity (and I cannot replace this anytime soon).

Answer (score 4):

Unity supports Lazy. You need to add the following extension to unity:

```
unityContainer.AddNewExtension<LazySupportExtension>();
```

then you can do the following:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IComponent, Component1>(); 
var lazyComponent = unityContainer.Resolve<Lazy<IComponent>>();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where's that extension from? It's not in the Unity DLL anywhere.

Comment: See: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=PierreCode&ReleaseId=4357

Comment: https://github.com/pwlodek/CodeGallery/blob/master/src/Unity.Extensions/Unity.Extensions/LazySupportExtension.cs